# Search string in file on UNC

Tags: python, windows

I have the following running on windows 2008 r2 and python 3.4

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This program process arguments")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--date", dest="date",
               help="Process a specific date in the format %%y/%%m/%%d", default="today")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="file",
               help="Vendor Filename", default="test.csv")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--server", dest="server",
               help="Reindex all files for a specific server (for all available dates")

args = parser.parse_args()
print ("Passed Date:%s" % args.date)
print ("Passed File:%s" % args.file)
print ("Passed Server:%s" % args.server)

fileHandle = open ( '//server/data/vendor/2014/04/02/%s' % args.file)
lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
fileHandle.close()

print (lineList[-1])
```

It only works if I have the fileHandle like mentioned above it doesn't work if I have it like a traditional windows format of '\server\data\vendor\yyyy\mm\dd\%s

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
fileHandle = open ( r'\\server\data\vendor\2014\04\02\%s' % args.file)
```

that r needs to be there to specify the string.